# How to disable "unnecessary test for null" warning in NetBeans 14?

Tags: java, netbeans, null-check, netbeans-14

### Short Version

How do i disable the "unnecessary test for null" warning in NetBeans 14 IDE?

[image]

### Long Version

NetBeans as a well-known bug <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086775/12597) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29106099/12597) [3](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226923) [4](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262707)</sup> where it will erroneously tell you that a test for `null` is unnecessary. For example in the following code:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

private void doSomething(@NotNull Object o) {
   
   if (o == null) return;

   //...do more stuff...
}
```

The IDE *thinks*

- because the `o` parameter was tagged as <kbd>@NotNull</kbd>`o`
- it must be **impossible** for `o` to be `null`
- so it must be that the `if` statement is unnecessary

### This is demonstrably false

The <kbd>@NotNull</kbd> annotation is only an IDE hint, not a runtime guarantee.

- just because an argument to a method is tagged as <kbd>@NotNull</kbd>able
- does not mean it cannot be `null`

You can prove this to yourself by passing `null` to the `doSomething` method. (we can even write the test code so the IDE generates no hints or warnings at all!):

```
Object o = getTestValue();
doSomething(o);

private Object getTestValue()
{
    Object o = null;
    return o;
}

private void doSomething(@NotNull Object o) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(value);
    //...do more stuff...
}
```

And watch `doSomething` method fail - because `o` is `null` - even though it is tagged <kbd>@NotNull</kbd>.

Now, there may be other implementations of `@NotNull`, or other compilers that add runtime checks. I'm not talking about those. The NetBeans IDE 14 warning is wrong, so i need to disable it.

### Research Effort

1. I tried clicking the lightbulb, to hopefully configure the warning:

[image]

but it only offers to configure *null deference* warnings - **which i definitely want to keep**.

2. I tried pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up more options:

[image]

but nothing of value appears:

3. I tried to let it bring me to the area to configure the **Null dereferncing** hint:

[image]

but it definitely has **nothing** to do with *unnecessary test for null.

4. I tried searching for a hint or warning named *"null"*:

[image]

but it's not there.

5. I tried searching for a hint or warning named *"unnecessary"*:

[image]

but it's not there.

6. I tried searching for a hint or warning named *"test"*:

[image]

but it's not there.

### How to turn it off

Which brings me to my question:

- given that NetBeans IDE 14 has no way to turn off *"unnecessary test for null"* warning
- how do i turn off the *"unnecessary test for null"* warning in NetBeans IDE 14?

## Bonus Reading

- [What does unnecessary test for null mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28404608)
- [Netbeans tells me to remove null comparison, but that breaks my code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22750489) *("First thing to note is: NetBeans is wrong")*
- BugZilla: [Bug 226923 - Wrong warning 'the expression is never null'](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=226923)
- Bugzilla: [Bug 262707 - Add configuration of Nullable/NonNull annotations. Use FQNs or allow to exclude FQNs.](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=262707)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it cannot be done.

NetBeans provides no way to disable the **unnecessary test for null** warning.

### Workaround

As other people in other answers have noted:

- the value **can** be null
- NetBeans is wrong thinking it cannot be null

The correct way to resolve the (incorrect) warning is to *obfuscate* the check for null.

Rather than calling:

```
if (customer == null) { ... }
```

Instead call:

```
if (Object.isNull(customer)) { ... }
```

It is the same thing; except this way NetBeans doesn't realize that you're testing the variable for `null`, and so doesn't warn you.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the "*Unnecessary test for null*" warning using the Java annotation `@SuppressWarnings("null")`. That annotation is found in **java.lang**, and there is no need for an import.

[The OpenJDK Javadoc for SuppressWarnings for JDK 17 states](https://devdocs.io/openjdk%7E17/java.base/java/lang/suppresswarnings):

> Indicates that the named compiler warnings should be suppressed in the
> annotated element (and in all program elements contained in the
> annotated element) ... As a matter of style, programmers should always
> use this annotation on the most deeply nested element where it is
> effective. If you want to suppress a warning in a particular method,
> you should annotate that method rather than its class.

From [the linked documentation to section 9.6.4.5 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.5), `@SuppressWarnings` appears to do exactly what you want, with my emphasis added:

> 9.6.4.5. @SuppressWarnings
>
> Java compilers are increasingly capable of issuing helpful "lint-like"
> warnings. To encourage the use of such warnings, **there should be some
> way to disable a warning in a part of the program when the programmer
> knows that the warning is inappropriate**.

Here's sample code, based on that in the OP:

```
package suppression;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull; // Jakarta EE 8
//import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull; // Jakarta EE 9

public class Suppression {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Suppression supp = new Suppression();
        Object o = supp.getTestValue();
        supp.doSomething(o);
        supp.doSomething2(o);
    }

    Object getTestValue() {
        Object o = null;
        return o;
    }

    private void doSomething(@NotNull Object o) {
        
        if (o == null) {
            System.out.println("Object is null!");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    private void doSomething2(@NotNull Object o) {
        
        if (o == null) {
            System.out.println("Object is null!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of that code in NetBeans 14 which shows:

- The unwanted warning "*Unnecessary test for null*" is shown on line 22 in method `doSomething()`.
- The annotation `@SuppressWarnings("null")` on line 27 prevents the unwanted warning "*Unnecessary test for null*" being shown on line 30 in the otherwise identical method `doSomething2()`.

[image: SuppressWarnings]

Comment: Unfortunately `@SuppressWarnings("null")` suppresses *`Dereference null pointer`* warning: **which**, as i said in the original question, **i definitely want to keep**. The question is how to disable *"unnecessary test for null"* (and not disable anything else)

Comment: OK - in that case you should clarify your precise question because the title, the opening sentence and the closing sentence are all only asking how to disable/turn off  the _"unnecessary test for null"_ warning, and my answer explained how to do that. What you seem to want is to turn off the compiler warning, yet still retain the associated NetBeans hint, and I suspect that can't be done. Regardless, your question needs clarification.

Comment: It isn't a compiler warning; there is no compiler warning emitted by Java, or the Java compiler, saying "unnecessary test for null". Java does not do that. Java does not check for *unnecessary check for null*. That is why it is not a Java question. It is a **NetBeans** question. That is why it was tagged as a **NetBeans** question: hoping to solve this **NetBeans** issue with **NetBeans** giving an incorrect warning in **NetBeans**.

Comment: OK. Regardless, you still need to clarify your question, and while it's tough to prove a negative, the evidence seems pretty clear that what you seem to want can't be done in NetBeans.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that i want to disable the *"unnecessary test for null"* warning in NetBeans 14 IDE, and i put it in big bold writing that i **do not want to disable null reference checking**.

Comment: [1] OK, but your title, opening sentence and closing sentence are still just asking how to disable "unnecessary test for null" and nothing more, so it remains unclear. [2] It seems implausible to claim that the _"Null dereferencing hint...definitely has nothing to do with *unnecessary test for null"_, given that the @SuppressWarnings("null") annotation suppresses both messages, or am I misunderstanding your point? (To be clear, I am not referring to what _should_ happen, but to what _does_ happen.)

Comment: I want to disable *unnecessary test for null* warning. I do **not** want to disable *dereference null pointer* warning.